# FileUpload in form HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, file-upload, oledb

I have a Website and in one webpage there is a form, where one of the fields is to upload an image. I have created in my database a column **picture** of type **LONGBINARY**. I have read some webpages where they explain how to use `<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>`. But the doubt is that I have an **input tag** `<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Put In Store" />` for my **form**. All the webpages where they explain about **FileUpload** are using a ***ASP button***, but for my form I need an **submit input**.

So:

- What do I do if it says I need a ASP Button but I need a submit input?
- Where need to be the code of the FileUpload when you click?

[My last question about FileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30800437/code-for-attaching-files-in-a-website/30801007?noredirect=1#comment49654779_30801007)(There are the links they gave me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload a file using your way. Just in the form tag, do mention the type attribute **type** as **multipart data**. So when you click on Submit the request goes to the place that is mentioned in the **action** attribute of the form tag.

Example form tag:

```
<form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```